# How to apply inner html to multiple elements easily?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Sorry if the title for this question is quite generic. I just really cannot formulate the logic for my problem.

As an overview, I am doing a landing page which will contain multiple languages, KO, SC, TC, JP to be specific. This landing page is a download page. So you can imagine it has the normal fields like Name, Email Address, Country and Company Name.

I already have the English labels laid down. The logic is, I will depend the change in field labels to a parameter. Ex. site.com?lang=sc will show SC field labels.

My basic approach is this:

```
if(lang == "sc") { $("#lblFirstName").html("SC Value"); }
```

It goes for all. However, I have 15 fields plus four languages. So its like I need to the four conditions on lang with 15 inner HTMLs there.

Will there be any shortcut on how to address updating each labels with minimized line of codes?

Any ideas/suggestions will be so much appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: use a language file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First save your translations in this object structure:

```
{
    'lang' => {'key1' => 'translation1', ...},
    'lang2' => {'key1' => 'translation1', ...},
    ...
}
```

Than loop your object and translate key-indicated fields.

```js
var translations = {
  'en': {
    'first-value': 'EN value', 'title': 'Some title'
  },
  'sc': {
    'first-value': 'SC value', 'title': 'AbraKadabra'
  }
}

function doTranslate(lang) {
  $.each(translations[lang], function(key, value) {
    $('[data-t-' + key + ']').text(value);
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select onChange="doTranslate($(this).val())">
  <option value="en">EN</option>
  <option value="sc">SC</option>
</select>
<hr/>
<span data-t-title>Some title</span> | 
<span data-t-first-value>EN value</span>
```

Comment: Is it the snippet tool that's broken when you choose from the dropdown? `"message": "Uncaught TypeError: translate is not a function",`

Comment: @DarrenSweeney Works on FF

Comment: On chrome I see: `Error: {
  "message": "Uncaught TypeError: translate is not a function",
  "filename": "http://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 12,
  "colno": 45
}`

Comment: @DarrenSweeney Fixed naming issue.

Comment: Thank you Sir @Justinas, this is what I am looking for. Thank you for introducing me to object structure.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to apply inner html to multiple elements, then you can use a class for all the element and apply inner html to that particular class.

```
$('.langClass').html(lang+" value");
```

Comment: this literally answers the question in the title. +1

Answer (score 0):

You should use international library. There are a lot of them from google, 
e.g.

a popular and easy to use one is jquery.i18n
please see sample code and tutorial here > https://github.com/wikimedia/jquery.i18n